# Reactjs - Accessing Post directly or hard refresh lead to blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, page-refresh

i have been tiring to solve this problem for two days but no luck
This is my first project with react v18.1, basically I'm stuck with single post,
Going from blog list to single post Loads fine, but if I refresh (Browser refresh button) single post or try to access to it directly I get blank page

It's Like the data won't load unless It passes through Blog List.

**This is my Route from index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import './index.css';
import './global.css';
import App from './App';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';
import Blog from './components/Blog';
import Doctors from './components/Doctors';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import Singlepost from './components/singlepost';
import Home from './components/Home';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} >
        <Route path="Doctors" element={<Doctors />} />
        <Route path="Blog" element={<Blog />} />
        <Route path="blog/:articleId" element={<Singlepost />} />
        <Route path="About" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="Contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Route>

    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

**Code from App.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "./components/header/header";
import Footer from "./components/footer";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  // storing the current page number and data in state
  const [blogData, setBlogData] = useState([]);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/blogpost.json`);

  // Fetching data from json file
  const dataFetch = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }

    });
    const data = await response.json();

    setBlogData(data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    dataFetch()

  }, []);


  return (
    <>

      <Header />
      <div className="flex flex-col my-20">
        <Outlet context={[blogData]} />
      </div>
      <Footer />

    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Code from blog.js page**

```
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link, Outlet, useOutletContext, } from 'react-router-dom';
import Pagination from './Pagination';

let PageSize = 10;
const MAX_LENGTH = 500;

export default function Blog() {

  const [articles] = useOutletContext();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);


  // pagination relation function
  let currentTableData = useMemo(() => {
    const firstPageIndex = (currentPage - 1) * PageSize;
    const lastPageIndex = firstPageIndex + PageSize;
    return articles.slice(firstPageIndex, lastPageIndex);
  }, [currentPage, articles]);

  function slugify(text) {
    return text.toString().toLowerCase()
      .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
      .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
      .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
      .replace(/^-+/, '')             // Trim - from start of text
      .replace(/-+$/, '');            // Trim - from end of text
  }

  return (
    <>

      {
        currentTableData.map(doc => (
          <div key={crypto.randomUUID()} className="flex flex-col md:flex-row w-full m-auto mb-4 shadow rounded border">
            <div>
              <img src={doc.Image_URL} alt="doctor" className="w-full h-64 md:h-auto md:w-64 rounded-l md:mr-4 max-h-[200px]" />

            </div>

            <div className='flex flex-col'>
              <Link to={`/blog/${doc.ID}`} className='font-semibold'>{doc.Title}</Link>
              <div className='flex flex-col'>

                {doc.Content.length > MAX_LENGTH ?
                  (
                    <div className='prose lg:prose-xl' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: doc.Content.substring(0, MAX_LENGTH) }}>

                    </div>
                  ) :
                  <p className='prose lg:prose-xl' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: doc.Content }} ></p>
                }

                <span>{doc.Category}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        ))
      }
      <Outlet context={[articles]} />
      <Pagination
        key={crypto.randomUUID()}
        data-link={crypto.randomUUID()}
        className="pagination-bar"
        currentPage={currentPage}
        totalCount={articles.length}
        pageSize={PageSize}
        onPageChange={page => setCurrentPage(page)}
      />


    </>
  )
}
```

**SinglePost.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useOutletContext, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Singlepost() {

  let params = useParams();

  const [blogData] = useOutletContext();


  const blogPost = blogData.find(blog => blog.ID === parseInt(params.articleId));


  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row w-full m-auto mb-4 shadow rounded border">
      <div>
        <img src={blogPost.Image_URL} alt="doctor" className="w-full h-64 md:h-auto md:w-64 rounded-l md:mr-4 max-h-[200px]" />

      </div>
      <div className='flex flex-col'>
        <h2 className='font-semibold'>{blogPost.Title}</h2>
        <div className='flex flex-col'>
          <div className='prose lg:prose-xl' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: blogPost.Content }}></div>
          <span>{blogPost.Category}</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

**Error after hard refresh**

```
singlepost.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Image_URL')
    at Singlepost (singlepost.js:17:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26422:1
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    singlepost.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Image_URL')
    at Singlepost (singlepost.js:17:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26422:1)
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
react-dom.development.js:18572 The above error occurred in the <Singlepost> component:

    at Singlepost (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1857:75)
    at Outlet (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68128:26)
    at div
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38:82)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68220:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:68153:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66962:5)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Image_URL')
    at Singlepost (singlepost.js:17:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27381:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26422:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26390:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25806:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25706:1)
```

I appreciates any thoughts.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the console in the browser whether there is any error that occurs when you hard refresh the page?

Comment: @maxagno3 i add the error log to main post, it's like the data won't load unless i access blog page first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You are forgetting that `array.prototype.find` returns `undefined` when no match is found in the array.

```
const blogPost = blogData.find(blog => blog.ID === parseInt(params.articleId));
```

In this case it's because the `blogData` array is empty and there is no match to be found.

This alone isn't what causes the problem, it's only the first step in leading to thrown errors. The error is thrown when later trying to render the found result and attempting to access into an undefined value.

```
<img
  src={blogPost.Image_URL} // <-- can't access Image_URL of undefined!
  alt="doctor"
  className="......"
/>
```

## Solution

There are a few things you can do to improve the code.

1. Check that there is a renderable `blogPost` object. Conditionally render the single post UI.

   ```
   export default function Singlepost() {
     const { articleId } = useParams();
     const [blogData] = useOutletContext();

     const blogPost = blogData.find(blog => String(blog.ID) === articleId);

     if (!blogPost) return null;

     return (
       ... blogPost ...
     );
   }
   ```
2. Expose the `dataFetch` in the context so blog posts can be fetched from children if necessary. They can render some loading indicator if desired.

   App

   ```
   function App() {
     // storing the current page number and data in state
     const [blogData, setBlogData] = useState([]);
     const [url, setUrl] = useState(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/blogpost.json`);

     // Fetching data from json file
     const dataFetch = async () => {
       const response = await fetch(url, {
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Accept': 'application/json'
         }
       });
       const data = await response.json();

       setBlogData(data);
     }

     useEffect(() => {
       dataFetch();
     }, []);

     return (
       <>
         <Header />
         <div className="flex flex-col my-20">
           <Outlet context={{ blogData, dataFetch }} />
         </div>
         <Footer />
       </>
     );
   }
   ```

   SinglePost

   ```
   export default function Singlepost() {
     const { articleId } = useParams();
     const { blogData, dataFetch } = useOutletContext();

     const blogPost = blogData.find(blog => String(blog.ID) === articleId);

     useEffect(() => {
       if (!blogPost) {
         dataFetch();
       }
     }, [blogPost, dataFetch]);

     if (!blogPost) return null; // or loading spinner/etc...

     return (
       ... blogPost ...
     );
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you it worked after adding the condition, i like the way you think, adding a fallback i did the exact thing after i noticed the app render twice, the first with an empty array then with data but somehow it didn't work for me, i guess because i was missing the Condition.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because you are trying to access a property of an object that is not defined yet: `blogPost`.

What you can do to avoid it's add a conditional render in **SinglePost.js** like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useOutletContext, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Singlepost() {

  let params = useParams();

  const [blogData] = useOutletContext();


  const blogPost = blogData.find(blog => blog.ID === parseInt(params.articleId));

  if(!blogPost) {
    return <h1>No blogpost yet</h1>
  }


  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row w-full m-auto mb-4 shadow rounded border">
      <div>
        <img src={blogPost.Image_URL} alt="doctor" className="w-full h-64 md:h-auto md:w-64 rounded-l md:mr-4 max-h-[200px]" />

      </div>
      <div className='flex flex-col'>
        <h2 className='font-semibold'>{blogPost.Title}</h2>
        <div className='flex flex-col'>
          <div className='prose lg:prose-xl' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: blogPost.Content }}></div>
          <span>{blogPost.Category}</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

One thing that you should do is manage the component when the data is loading.

Comment: Thank you, after cleaning the code and adding that condition it worked , even though I still don't understand why

Comment: JS throws an error if it's trying to read a property from an undefined object